Confusion regarding some vector calculus identities
According to Wikipedia, for vectors $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$,
$$(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{A}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{B}).$$
But since the dot product is commutative we have
$$(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}=(\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A}.$$
Later in the same article here, we have
$$\nabla(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B})=(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B})+\mathbf{B}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A})=(\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A}+(\nabla\mathbf{A})\cdot\mathbf{B},$$
however by the above identity this is
$$\nabla(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B})=(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}.$$
Meaning the cross product terms are neglected. What's going wrong here?

Note that the dot product is not commutative when operators are involved.

The cross product is not being neglected. Just a little lower in the article you link to it says:
$$\mathbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B}) = (\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{B})$$
so
\begin{align}
\nabla(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B})
&=(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B})+\mathbf{B}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{A})\\
&=(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}+(\mathbf{B}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{A}
+(\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A} - \mathbf{A}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{B})
+(\nabla\mathbf{A})\cdot\mathbf{B} - \mathbf{B}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{A})
\\
&=(\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A}+(\nabla\mathbf{A})\cdot\mathbf{B},
\end{align}
Note that $\mathbf{A}$ is a vector, so $\nabla\mathbf{A}$ is not a vector, but a matrix, the $ij$ element of $(\nabla\mathbf{A})^T$ is $ \partial A_i/\partial x_j$, the Jacobian of $\mathbf{A}$, which isn't symmetric, so $(\nabla\mathbf{A})\cdot\mathbf{B} \ne\mathbf{B}\cdot(\nabla\mathbf{A})$.

Yeah, your first statement essentially re-states my issue. If $(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{B}=(\nabla\mathbf{B})\cdot\mathbf{A}$, then $\mathbf{A}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{B})=0$. But as you say, that's where I'm going wrong; I can't commute the dot product in this case. Thanks!
